# forming a table with given lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

So I have been stuck on this problem for a few hours now and am in need of some assistance.

[image]

I have tried using pandas to complete it, but that didn't work...I need to find a way to add a value that represents the sum of each nested list in the list counts, and I know I need to use a for loop but I'm sure how else to form it with append when doing it with nested loops. I think the best way to go about this would be by using a dictionary, but again, I am not sure how to approach this. I know I am asking for a lot, but if anyone has any ideas that would be great!

Comment: We will not do your entire homework for you, only help you with it. Show us your code and focus on a specific problem you're having. Tell us what you already understood, where you are struggling, and [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you are allowed to use Pandas:**

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(counts, index = countries) 
df.columns = ['Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze' 
df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

Output on sample data:

```
       Gold  Silver  Bronze  Total
Canda     0       3       0      3
Italy     0       0       1      1
```

Comment: not sure if I'm allowed to, but this is very helpful thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code without using Pandas :

```
def print_model(countries, counts):
    print("                  {:8s}{:8s}{:8s}{:8s}".format("Gold", "Silver", "Bronz", 
"Total" ))
    for i in range(0, len(countries)):
        sum = 0
        print("{:<12s}".format(countries[i]), end = "")
        for j in range(0, 3):
            print("{:8d}".format(counts[i][j]), end = "")
            sum += counts[i][j]
        print("{:8d}".format(sum))

print_model(countries, counts)
```